# How to install MongoDb in MacOS Catalina version 10.15?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to install MongoDb in my Macbook,
My OS version is **MacOS Catalina version 10.15.4**

**I tried the following commands -**
1. brew update
2. brew install mongodb-community

But I am getting the following error -

```
Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/share/man/man5
/usr/local/share/man/man7

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7

And make sure that your user has write permission.
  chmod u+w /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7
```

**Also tried -**
[image]

**Do I need to run these commands thrown in the error? -**

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7

chmod u+w /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7
```

Comment: have you tried to install this with super user? like sudo brew install mongodb-community?

Comment: @OEH yes, shared the screenshot in the question

Comment: Is installing It manually an option? I had this issue as well and i opt for manually installation

Comment: oh nvm I just had to run those two commands, able to install now

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by running the commands in the error message -

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7

chmod u+w /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7
```